# How to Create new folders under Res in Eclipse Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to create a new folder "layout_land" for landscape layout xmls.
When I create a new folder under res, and clean and rebuild ro regenerate R.java, I still find that the folder is showing up as an error.
I have tried clean / rebuild before creating and soon after but its no use.
Do suggest a solution.
Regards
Indrajit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folder should be called layout-land not layout_land. That should work.